# How to get nested 3 label array object in Mongo Query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Basically the structure is :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123123"),
    "stores" : [
        {
            "messages" : [
                {
                    "updated_time" : "2018-05-15T05:12:25+0000",
                    "message_count" : 4,
                    "thread_id" : "123",
                    "messages" : [
                        {
                            "message" : "Hi User ",
                            "created_time" : "2018-05-15T05:12:25+0000",       
                            "message_id" : "111",
                        },
                        {
                            "message" : "This is tes",
                            "created_time" : "2018-05-15T05:12:21+0000",
                            "message_id" : "222",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ],
            "store_id" : "123"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have these values to get message_id object : 111. So how to get this object, any idea or help will be appreciated. THanks

```
store_id: 123,
thread_id:123,
message_id:111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) all the nested arrays and then use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to get single document. You can also add [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get only nested document. Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {  $unwind: "$stores" },
    {  $unwind: "$stores.messages" },
    {  $unwind: "$stores.messages.messages" },
    {  $match: { "stores.store_id": "123", "stores.messages.thread_id": "123", "stores.messages.messages.message_id": "111" } },
    {  $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$stores.messages.messages" } }
])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "created_time": "2018-05-15T05:12:25+0000",
    "message": "Hi User ",
    "message_id": "111"
}
```

To improve the performance you can use `$match` after every `$unwind` to filter out unnecessary data as soon as possible, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {  $unwind: "$stores" },
    {  $match:  { "stores.store_id": "123" } },
    {  $unwind: "$stores.messages" },
    {  $match:  { "stores.messages.thread_id": "123" } },
    {  $unwind: "$stores.messages.messages" },
    {  $match: { "stores.messages.messages.message_id": "111" } },
    {  $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$stores.messages.messages" } }
])
```